# Javascript error - Can not find function UISearchBarTextField

Tags: javascript, ios, monkeytalk

I'm trying to get MonkeyTalk working with Javascript. I'm automating some tests with iOS.  When I run the .MT version, the test runs fine. But, the Javascript version errors with this.

ERROR sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function uISearchBarTextField. (RADialerDirectory.js#8) in RADialerDirectory.js at line number 8

The export javascript code shows this:

`this.app.uISearchBarTextField().tap();`

Anyone know how to get around this error?  I'm just trying to use the Javascript version of the script to loop and later grab external data to iterate through.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for "UIAleartView". There are three ways to get it work. this happen because MonkeyTalkAPI.js file doesn't contain an entry for "uISearchBarTextField"

1. Use more generic type(Input) like above answer.
2. Set accessibilityLabel property of that component and use it as a monkeyID like here: [MonkeyTalk : Verify custom UITableViewCell Label text without select the cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304129/monkeytalk-verify-custom-uitableviewcell-label-text-without-select-the-cell)
3. A little hack to MonkeyTalkAPI.js class. find the word for "Input" which is more generic to your "uISearchBarTextField" and get a copy of it paste it again in that file and edit replaceing "Input" with  "uISearchBarTextField" save it and run. if you did it carefully it works.

Happy Testting